# Generic static methods without brackets, e.g. in JavaFX 8

Tags: java, javafx

I've defined a GUI within a FXML file and have the following code in the corresponding controller:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<Abnormality, String> abnormalityTableViewStatusTableColumn;
```

later in the `initialize()`-method I have:

```
abnormalityTableViewStatusTableColumn.setCellFactory(
            ComboBoxTableCell.<Abnormality, String> forTableColumn("Option1", "Option2", "Option3"));
```

([API TableColumn - method setCellFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) and [API ComboBoxTableCell - method forTableColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/ComboBoxTableCell.html#forTableColumn-javafx.collections.ObservableList-))

But the compiler would also accept

```
abnormalityTableViewStatusTableColumn.setCellFactory(
            ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn("Option1", "Option2", "Option3"));
```

without the generic brackets.

Does the compiler automatically resolve the types in the second case?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; Java 8 contains some improvements over previous versions in type-inference. In Java 8 the compiler is able to infer from the context (you are passing the result of `forTableColumn` into a method that is expecting a `Callback<TableColumn<Abnormality, String>, TableCell<Abnormality, String>>`) that the type for the generic method is `<Abnormality, String>`. Because the compiler can make this inference, explicitly providing the types is not required.